# how to assign a word table in the center of the page

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32, win32com

### center a word table

i am working with python and word application

i am trying to generate a table which will be in the middle of the page.

i tried something like this :

```
oWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```

---

i had tried to assign it to 1 but it does not matter

```
oWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
```

---

thank you for any help

Comment: Do you want to center the table on page or center cell content within each cell?  How do you know that your selection is the table?

Comment: i meant to center the table on the page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 oWord.Tables[1].Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```

// Where Tables[1] means first table into your document. It Would definitely work

Answer (score 1):

Try recording a macro where you execute the ops you want and looking at resulting VB, this may then be easy to translate to python.